# Taking so much time for launching app on real time device in android studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.1

Actually the thing is that whenever I am going to execute my project from android studio its taking too much time means like 30 to 40 minute maybe more and sometime its immediately launch only when I sync my gradel with very minor changes.
currently I have been using android studio 2.1 and I didn't do major changes in gradle despite this,android studio taking too much time to execute project. following is my gradle contains.

dependencies {`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //This line is added
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    //Volley Library
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

}

Comment: what is your system configuration and which os are you using?

Comment: @Shailesh My system configuration is 4.00 GB RAM and 32-bit OS with windows 7 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 processor and I think its not issue related to system configuration and android studio working fine with this configuration since many days and might be there would be problem with the contains of gradle.

Comment: Look when you install Android Studio then its by default required 2GB RAM so your 2 GB RAM is reserved. Now next you have just remain 2GB RAM for other processs and if you installed other software then they are also using your RAM. Other think is you are using 32-bit Win 7 so data transformation is in 32-bit instead of 64-bit so its quite slower then 64-bit Win OS. You can check memory uses and load by using Windows Task Manager. I suggest you try your code with other high configuration system, like Win 7 64-bit, 8GB RAM so you will get better idea.

Comment: But without getting any obstacle I am running my project in android studio with current configuration but think is that whenever I am going  to execute my project its taking too much time for launching on real time device I think there is something goes wrong.

Comment: Have you tried by re-install your windows and android studio?

Comment: @Shailesh actually there is no any issue with Gradle or with PC's specification actually want to tell u that I am using Lenovo a6000 device for testing and whenever I am testing app on this device its taking too much time to launch on it but I tested app on different device like Lenovo Tab its launching in normal time.
there would be issue with my Lenovo a6000 device.